# visualize the value distribution for a given numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scikit-image, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix, e.g., generated as follows

```
x = np.random.randint(10,size=(20,20))
```

How to visualize the matrix with respect to the distribution of a given value, i.e., 6
In other words, how to show the matrix as an image, where the pixels with corresponding matrix entries being equivalent to 6 will be shown as white, while other pixels will be shown as black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to display the distribution of a given value through a black and white image is using a boolean array like `x == 6`. If you wish to improve visualization by replacing black and white with custom colors, NumPy's [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will come in handy:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 20))

value = 6
foreground = [255, 0, 0]  # red
background = [0, 0, 255]  # blue

bw = x == value
rgb = np.where(bw[:, :, None], foreground, background)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(bw, cmap='gray')
ax[0].set_title('Black & white')
ax[1].imshow(rgb)
ax[1].set_title('RGB')
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: output]

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you for your remark. I've edited my answer to make it more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Initialise data
x = np.random.randint(10,size=(20,20),dtype=np.uint8)

# Make all pixels with value 6 into white and all else black
x[x==6]   = 255
x[x!=255] = 0

# Make PIL Image from Numpy array
pi = Image.fromarray(x) 

# Display image
pi.show()

# Save PIL Image
pi.save('result.png')
```

[image]